# while including this code of sidebar menu in any page of php the dropdown is working onclick but when clicked again the menu is not going up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, onclick, sidebar

```
<link href="css/SideMenuBar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- Optional theme -->

<div class="nav-side-menu">
     <div class="menu-list">

            <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard
                  </a>
                </li>

                 <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#service" class="collapsed">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Services <span class="arrow"></span></a>
                </li>  
                <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="service">
                  <li>New Service 1</li>
                  <li>New Service 2</li>
                  <li>New Service 3</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

As per the code given, drop down menu in side bar when we click on services to have more option it appears but when we click again to close it doesn't close.

Comment: try to add your full code